# How to make child div to take the size of parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a placeholder view of my page until the actual page is loaded.

I want this `div` **element** to take the size of its **parent** `div`

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-push-3 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-push-3 property-masker-sub-four-one"></div>
```

Check the **snippet**. It's a thin **green line**. I want it to be the size of its **parent** `div` and I will give it a white color so that it will look like a whitespace and the grey shimmering area before that will look like a `button`.

```css
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
    0%{
        background-position: -368px 0
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 368px 0
    }
}

.calendar-wrapper, .property-wrapper, .paid-wrapper, .details-wrapper{
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #e5e6e9 #dfe0e4 #d0d1d5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 250px;
    /*margin-left: 40px;*/
}

.paid-wrapper{
    min-height: 160px;
}

.calendar-wrapper{
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #f6f7f8;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 800px 104px;
}

.paid-wrapper{
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #f6f7f8;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 800px 104px;
}

.property-wrapper{
 min-height: 150px;
}

.details-wrapper{
    min-height: 350px;
}

.property-animated-background, .details-animated-background {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #f6f7f8;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 800px 104px;
    height: 170px;
}

.details-animated-background{
    height: 350px;
}

.property-masker-one{
 padding: 15px 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.property-masker-two{
    padding: 17px 0;
}

.property-masker-three{
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.property-masker-four{
    padding: 17px 0;
}

.property-masker-sub-four-one{
    background-color: green;
}

.property-masker-five{
    padding: 16px 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
 <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 calendar-wrapper"></div>

   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 property-wrapper">
    <div class="property-animated-background">
     <div class="property-masker-one"></div>
     <div class="property-masker-two"></div>
     <div class="property-masker-three"></div>
     <div class="property-masker-four">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-push-3 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-push-3 property-masker-sub-four-one"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="property-masker-five"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 paid-wrapper"></div>

   <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 details-wrapper">
    <div class="details-animated-background">
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

 </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I want it like this

[image: I want it like this]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't really understand what you're trying to achieve with this but if you want an element to be the exact same size of its parent, you can add `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the child element with both `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` properties set to zero.

Comment: Yes I tried that. I gave it a `left` and `width` property after adding `position: relative` to parent and `position: absolute` to child and placed it exactly where I want it to but then it wont work on mobile devices. It's not responsive.

Comment: Why not? You could use % values to make it responsive. Let's say your elements are 20px large. The first one has `left: 33.3%` and the second one has `left: 66.6%`. Then you give a `margin-left: -10px` to both elements to center them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what your are trying to achieve.

Add two child elements to your property-masker-four (note that I removed all the bootstrap classes because we want custom size and position)

```
<div class="property-masker-four">
    <div class="property-masker-sub-four-one"></div>
    <div class="property-masker-sub-four-two"></div>
</div>
```

In your CSS, just give relative to the parent and position absolute to the child ones. Place the first one to 33% from the left and the second one to 66% from the left to keep things responsive. Then give both a negative margin-left equal to half their size.

```
.property-masker-four {
    position: relative;
    padding: 17px 0;
}

.property-masker-sub-four-one, .property-masker-sub-four-two {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.property-masker-sub-four-one{
    left: 33.33%;
}
.property-masker-sub-four-two{
    left: 66.66%;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cb8kov38/) is the fiddle

Comment: Yea I was trying that. It Works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this codepen.

A div element to take the size of its parent div

```
<div id="wrapper" class="col-sm-5">
<div class="row row-eq-height">

 <div class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-pied-piper fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

<div class="col-sm-10">
  <h1>Pied Piper</h1>Pied Piper takes all your files and makes them smaller for when you need a “little help”! It’s built on a universal compression engine that stacks on any file, data, video or image no matter what size.
  <p></p>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/arshohag/pen/pPvMdB